# How to get GUID (Assembly attribute) of a C# assembly in c++

Tags: c#, c++, attributes, guid

I am trying to read **GUID attribute** of a C#.net assembly from **c++** (VC++ 10).

I should mention that, I don't want to use .net or .net reflection. looking for a pure c++ way.

what is the solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited tags; [assembly] is for assembly-language questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [Unamanaged Metadata API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233411.aspx)

and especially the [IMetaDataImport::EnumCustomAttributes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231454.aspx)

That's going to be quite a work... Here is a link that gives a good starting point on this (it's C#, but the ideas are exactly the same, and is in fact easier to program in C++): [Reading types from assembly](http://pzsolt.blogspot.com/2005/01/reading-types-from-assembly.html)

Comment: I agree Farzi has definitely has a challenging task at hand. I almost want to try it for the challenge.

Comment: provided solution uses .net framework. I should not use any version of .net framework for this job.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Drop the restriction, it is nonsense.

Comment: @Farzin - I depend on what you mean by "uses .NET Framework". This solution does not use the CLR, it can be written in pure unmanaged C++. However it needs the .NET Framework binaries, yes. Otherwise, you should go for the raw .NET file format (as joe suggests).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [The .NET File Format](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/dotnetformat.aspx#MetaSection) MetaSection over at CodeProject.

Comment: Guid is a custom attribute of a c# assembly. provided format, does not talk about any custom attribute of assembly. provided attributes are: name, public key and ... not Guid

Comment: You are referring to this GUID commonly found in AssemblyInfo.cs correct? // The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff")]

Answer (score 0):

i understand you don't want to use reflection or .net.
You do however want to get the GUID from a C# dll you have, that was built with .NET.

The common way C# developers make their class libraries available to COM-based developers is to use the tlbexp.exe (type library export) tool to export a type library file.

The COM-developer can then use the .tlb file in their COM code.

When the C# developer builds the dll they either put the Guid manually in the AssemblyInfo level (in .NET) or the compiler will generate the Guid automatically when building the dll.

show how the COM client (C++) is built to use the COM server (C#)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645738%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

note that in this article refers to another tool regasm.exe which registers the dll and can export the tlb at the same time but it is not necessary to register the dll on your system

as a developer you can just use the tlb file